# Clarification of uses of different NoSQL databases

Tags: nosql

I understand it may seem a redundant question, but I hope it will clarify all my and other users doubts.

Here are the noSQL I am talking about can someone explain me:

1. The best use cases (When I should use it)
2. The pros and the cons (Limitations included)
3. Their added value (why it is better, possibly a mathematical/scientific explanation)

of MongoDB, Redis, CouchDB, Hadoop

Thanks

g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDb and CouchDb are **not** key-value storages, but document-stores.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to clarify doubts - reading technical documentation and overview =)

In short - MongoDb and CouchDb are fast enough, reliable key-value storages, that persist 
data to disc. MongoDb works over custom TCP/IP protocol, CouchDb use REST approach over HTTP

Redis is another kind of ket/value storage, that stores all data in memory, all writes and reads go directly to memory. This approach has some drawbacks and benefits as well. It persists changes at disc too

Hadoop is not just a key/value storage. It's an engine for the distributed processing of large data. If you are going to write Google you can use Hadoop.

In my opinion, if you are not going to build something specific (i think you won't), go ahead and use MongoDB.